# Better way to get browser culture in Blazor webassembly / client app

Tags: blazor, cultureinfo, webassembly, blazor-client-side, currentculture

I know how to get the current culture information for Blazor server app by using [HTTPContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1) with IRequestCultureFeature. Is there any better way to get current browser culture in Blazor webassembly (wasm) / client app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently client size Blazor does not have a way to get culture data because mono on webassembly does not implement it (yet - tracked on github).

As far as I know, your best option is going to be able to find it with javascript, and then send it to Blazor with `JsInterop`.

Something like this to get you started, in the index page in a script tag:

```
window.getCulture = function () {
    return (navigator.languages && navigator.languages.length) ? navigator.languages[0] : 
    navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || 'en';
}
```

Then in Blazor:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@code{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var browserLocale = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getCulture");
        Console.WriteLine(browserLocale);
    }
}
```

Then check the console window and you'll see the culture printed.

Edit: Actually someone made an open source package for this that may be easier to use:
https://github.com/Blazored/Localisation
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazored.Localisation/

Edit 2: Blazored.Localisation is deprecated, you can use Blazored.LocalStorage instead:
https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazored.LocalStorage/

Answer (score 2):

You can request the browser language using [JSInterop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```js
window.browserJsFunctions = {
    getLanguage: () => {
        return navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    },
    getBrowserTimeZoneOffset: () => {
        return new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    },
    getBrowserTimeZoneIdentifier: () => {
        return Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    },
};
```

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime
@code {
        string _cultureName;

        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                _cultureName = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("browserJsFunctions.getLanguage");
            }
        }
}
```