# Change culture info blazor web assembly, display name issue

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, globalization

I'm using localization in my blazor wasm application. But when loading and trying to display the name of the cultures, it does not show as intended. By following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#localization and many other tutorials, the displayName property should display German or French for the culture (de-De) and (fr-Fr).

But instead when I retrieve the differents cultures like this : `

```
Cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures).ToList();
```

And then displays it like this :

```
@foreach(var c in Cultures){
  <h1>@c.DisplayName</h1>
}
```

I get fr (Fr) or de (De) instead of the French/German I was expecting. Any ideas why it is not working?

PS: using .net 6.0 and VS 17.0.4

Comment: It might be because of this: [Blazor localization not working #16687](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16687) ?

Comment: This issue was solved since .net 5.0

Comment: And, which .NET version do you use? (it is not mentioned in your question, use [edit] to add that info)

Comment: Yup sorry, I added it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310206/better-way-to-get-browser-culture-in-blazor-webassembly-client-app same issue, closing this one

Answer (score 2):

What you get is a generic language type. You have to allow language and culture info changing.
Try to add in your wasmApplicationName.client.csproj (you find it in the application folder), as the last item of PropertyGroup, this directive:

```
<BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
```

Hope this is useful

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `CultureInfo.DisplayName/EnglishName/NativeName` are not supported in Blazor WASM.

The easiest way to get them is an Api-call to your server to load a dictionary with `{ CultureInfo.Name, CultureInfo.DisplayName }`

Comment: Is this working for you? Because this was already set in my project and this does not work :/

Comment: Unfortunately you are right @lioleveau. I use the `BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData` to solve [DateTime.TryParse with IFormatProvider does not work correct in Blazor WASM](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46327) and I expected it to load the language names too, but is doesn't. I will correct my answer.

Comment: The issue with what you're suggesting is that the displayName is always in the current OS language, it won't change unfortunately